# Question about integration limits in the special relativistic action

Tags: special-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, notation, integration, action

We can read in [this](https://hepweb.ucsd.edu/ph110b/110b_notes/node65.html#:%7E:text=What%20Action%20should%20we%20use,minimizes%20the%20space%2Dtime%20interval.) article that the action of a particle in special relativity, is

[image]

It seems like nitpicking maybe, but shouldn't the two coordinate time limits be changed to proper time limits, or are the limits purposely kept the same?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's a mistake and they should be changed, they become proper time limits in the next step.